# Is it possible to to create a vector filled with zeros of size N using template meta programming in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, compile-time

I'm learning more about template meta programming in c++ and after doing the standard generate primes and factorial in compile time I'm now trying to create a Matrix class in compile time. A subproblem of this is to create a vector of size `N` filled with zeros. Is this possible to do with template meta programming?

I'm thinking something like this.

```
template<int N>
struct Vec {
    static std::vector<int> vec;

    constexpr Vec(int count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            vec.push_back(0); 
        }
    }
};
```

But the compiler says that ´for-loops´ are not allowed in an constexpr constructor. Is there any way to achieve functionality like this in compile time.

Comment: Why does `Vec` take an integer template parameter *and* have a constructor with an integer argument?  Also do you *really* want a static non-const variable?

Comment: `std::array` is your friend here.

Answer (score 2):

> A subproblem of this is to create a vector of size N filled with zeros. Is this possible to do with template meta programming?

If with "vector" do you mean exactly "`std::vector`", no: isn't possible in C++11, C++14 or C++17. Maybe with future versions of the standard; not now.

If for "vector" do you accept a "`std::array`", yes: it's possible and trivially simple (no initialization function required)

```
constexpr std::array<int, 10> a{};  // zero initialized !
```

I suppose that your `Vec` could be written

```
template <std::size_t N> // better std::size_t for a size (IMHO)
struct Vec
 {
   std::array<int, N> vec; // no static for a member, please

   constexpr Vec () : vec{}
    { }
};
```

but seems to me that you can use directly a `std::array`.

> But the compiler says that ´for-loops´ are not allowed in an constexpr constructor. Is there any way to achieve functionality like this in compile time.

The compiler complain about a problem of different type: it's saying that, in C++11, a `constexpr` function can't contain a for-loop.

In C++11 a `constexpr` function can contain (simplifying a lot) only a `return` instruction. A `constexpr` constructor must be empty; only initialization list.

If you want a more complex `constexpr` function (with a for-loop in it) you need C++14.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote over main:

```
constexpr size_t N = 100;
constexpr std::vector<int> ZEROES(N, 0);
```

Which led to the conclusion that:

```
7:39: error: the type 'const std::vector<int>' of constexpr variable 'ZEROES' is not literal
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/vector:64:0,
                 from 4:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:214:11: note: 'std::vector<int>' is not literal because:
     class vector : protected _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:214:11: note:   'std::vector<int>' has a non-trivial destructor
```

Which means that you will not be able to create a compile time `std::vector` of any kind. However you can make an array, I don't know if it helps:

```
constexpr int ZEROES2[N] = {0};
```